# Python return statement Includes brackets

Tags: python

I have just started coding and have cleared most of my basics but I still have a problem understanding 'return' statements and None type variables in python.

```
def celtofar(x):
    far= (x*9/5) + 32
    if x<-273.15:
        return("The Value Of Celsius Entered is too low ")
    else:
        return ("Temperature in Fahrenheit Shall Be: ", far)
try :
    cel=int(input("Enter Temperature in celsius: "))
    print(celtofar(cel))
except ValueError :
    print("Please Enter an Integral Value")
```

I want the output without brackets and quotes but the terminal is giving me the following result:

```
PS C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\Work> python .\program1.py

Enter Temperature in celsius: 30
('Temperature in Fahrenheit Shall Be: ', 86.0)
```

I don't want the brackets and the quotes to be included.

Comment: All of your return values should share a consistent format, i.e. either both tuples or single strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `far` to a `str` and concatenate it with the result:

```
def celtofar(x):
   far = (x * 9 / 5) + 32
   if x < -273.15:
      return "The Value Of Celsius Entered is too low"
   else:
      return "Temperature in Fahrenheit Shall Be: " + str(far)

try:
    cel = int(input("Enter Temperature in celsius: "))
    print(celtofar(cel))
except ValueError:
    print("Please Enter an Integral Value")
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter Temperature in celsius: 30
Temperature in Fahrenheit Shall Be: 86.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**EDIT**:

However, I'd recommend using `str.format()`:

```
def celtofar(x):
    far = (x * 9 / 5) + 32
    if x < -273.15:
        return "The Value Of Celsius Entered is too low"
    else:
        return "Temperature in Fahrenheit Shall Be: {}".format(far)


def main():
    try:
         cel = int(input("Enter Temperature in celsius: "))
         print(celtofar(cel))
    except ValueError:
         print("Please Enter an Integral Value")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is cause your print is a tuple. Use this example to format the string in your print

```
    return ("Temperature in Fahrenheit Shall Be: %s" %far)
```

Comment: *% string operator will be deprecated – no longer used – in Python 3.1 and up*

Comment: Not only are the braces off-putting, but you've used old string formatting to boot. Have you heard of `str.format`?

Comment: @DirtyBit "Each of these alternatives provides their own trade-offs and benefits of simplicity, flexibility, and/or extensibility" https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting so it's not true to say that the "`%` string operator will be deprecated".